# Typescript object destructuring is caught by ESLint no-unused-vars rule

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have an object in Typescript that I am destructuring in order to extract a partial object. However, it fails my linter check:

```
async someFunction(username: string): Promise<UserDTO> {
    const userEntity = await getUserByUsernameAsync(username);

    if (userEntity ) {
        const { password, ...result } = userEntity ;
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

As you can see, the above code grabs an object and strips out some parts of the object that we don't want to return, and returns the rest of the object.

However, the linter gives a warning:

```
warning  'password' is assigned a value but never used      @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

The object destructuring is assigning `passport` to a value and `result` to another object value and `passport` is the one that isn't being used. How do I fix this issue in order to pass the linter?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can disable this verification for rest siblings adding `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "ignoreRestSiblings": true }]` to your list of rules in `eslintrc.js`.

Example:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
  ],
  extends: [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "ignoreRestSiblings": true }]
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: "detect"
    }
  }
};
```

You can also opt for disabling the linting rule for that line altogether adding this to the line above it:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Comment: For javascript and eslint use:
`"no-unused-vars":  ["error", { "ignoreRestSiblings": true }]`

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "varsIgnorePattern": "_", "ignoreRestSiblings": true  }]` ... do I have the syntax wrong?

Comment: @escapecharacter you may need the `argsIgnorePattern` if you're trying to allow arguments to have underscores https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern

Comment: This is not working for me either, in a spec file with typescript.
I have `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["warn", { argsIgnorePattern: "^_", varsIgnorePattern: "^_", ignoreRestSiblings: true }]` in eslintrc.js
Eslint detects the line as error:
`const { coordinates: _, ...inputWithoutCoordinates } = input;`

Answer (score 16):

It seems now days you will need these two rules added to your `.eslintrc.json`.

`argsIgnorePattern` will allow underscore arguments in your function signatures, while `varsIgnorePattern` will allow underscores in destructuring.

We're using the pattern: `^_` to make sure the variable name starts with an underscore.

### Example

```json
"rules": {
  "no-unused-vars": ["error", {
    "varsIgnorePattern": "^_",
    "argsIgnorePattern": "^_"
  }]
}
```

### Documentation

- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern
- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#varsignorepattern

### Notes

In the original question it is sufficient to utilize: `"ignoreRestSiblings": true` because it is in use with "rest siblings".

I would still recommend using an underscore prefix as an explicit notation. It's also worth noting that without the rest pattern, `ignoreRestSiblings` will not solve the problem when trying to destructure and utilizing underscore notation.

Comment: `varsIgnorePattern` is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

You can look to either remove the linter setting using the `ignoreRestSiblings` or pass the entire object and then look to delete the property.

```
async someFunction(username: string): Promise<UserDTO> {
    const userEntity = await getUserByUsernameAsync(username);

    if (userEntity ) {
        const {...result} = userEntity;
        delete result.password;
        return result
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: result is a shallow copy of `userEntity` and your approach will change the `userEntity` too

Comment: @farzad no it won't, the `password` property will be removed only from the shallow copy: https://replit.com/@fabiob/QuietJumpyGnudebugger

Comment: If you destructure `password` it will be removed from `result` and then you don't have to use `delete`. I.e. `const { password, ...result } = userEntity;`

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
const { field1: _, field2: __, ...rest } = yourObject;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35186361)